# Navigate through search results page and find the link using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Consider I have to do a **Google search** on a Macbook and I have to navigate through the search results page until I find the **eBay** link.

For example, if the eBay link is in the 3rd page of the search results page in Google, then my Selenium script should be clever enough to realize that pages 1 & 2 don't contain the eBay link and in the 3rd page it should click on the eBay link.

My pseudo-code tries to identify the eBay link using `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Ebay.co.uk"))`, but I am unsure how find the eBay link among search results page.

All I have tried is the following pseudo-code:

```
if (driver.isLinkPresent("Ebay.co.uk")) {
    then driver.findElement(By.linkText(Ebay)).click();
    Else 
            Navigate to next Search result page
})(Repeat the loop until the link is found);
```

Any ideas on how to take this to code level? Glad if anyone could help!

Comment: cool story. can you add some piece of code how did you tried.

Comment: Thanks Trimantra. I have updated the question with Pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be able to show you how, but as I have not used selenium with Java, I won't be able to provide the exact code.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
found = false;

while(found == false){

   attemptFind = $driver.findElements({xpath: "//h3[contains(text(),'eBay: Electronics')]"}); // Returns an array of headers are found with Ebay.co.uk in

   if attemptFind.length() == 0 || attemptFind == null {
      currentPage = $driver.findElement({css: "td.cur"}).getText(); // Get Current Page Number
      nextPage = (currentPage.toInt() + 1).toString(); // Add 1 to current page

      $driver.findElement({css: "a[aria-label='Page "+nextPage+"']"}).click(); // Go to next page
   } else {
      attemptFind[0].click(); // Click on the Ebay link
      found = true; // Break out of loop
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. sort of useful pseudo code to get an idea.